# Phalcon with php7.0 and php7.3

Tags: php, debian, phalcon

Debian 8, ISPConfig 3

Some time ago I've installed Phalcon with PHP 7.0.
Everything worked well.
But now I'd like to use PHP 7.3, without uninstalling the previous version.

I've installed PHP 7.3 and also everything works. I can switch between versions, but I can't install Phalcon with:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-phalcon
```

Here is the response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php-phalcon' instead of 'php7.3-phalcon'
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libtidy5
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-phalcon
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,322 kB of archives.
After this operation, 25.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 78237 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php-phalcon_3.4.2-1+0~20190104095752.4+stretch~1.gbp469dbc_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php-phalcon (3.4.2-1+0~20190104095752.4+stretch~1.gbp469dbc) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/php-phalcon_3.4.2-1+0~20190104095752.4+stretch~1.gbp469dbc_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/phalcon/php_phalcon.h', which is also in package php7.0-phalcon 3.4.3-1+php7.0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/php-phalcon_3.4.2-1+0~20190104095752.4+stretch~1.gbp469dbc_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried swapping php versions to 7.3 with `update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3` followed by purging and then re-installing the `php-phalcon` package?

Comment: Yes, I had, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file at `/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/phalcon/php_phalcon.h`. It seems that is where there is overlap.

Comment: Yes, i moved it with `mv php_phalcon.h php_phalcon.h.old` but got same error.

Comment: I solved problem with workaround... I compiled phalcon using other machine and manually copied phalcon.so file. Now everything works good. But I know is not best solution....